# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

hello am try to upload image to Storage of firestore

Am try with this code
to select and upload image with multi data to send but the error is with the images

that the code where I get the image

```
void getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      selectedImagePath.value = pickedFile.path;
    } else {
      Get.snackbar("Error", "No Image selected",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          colorText: Colors.white);
    }
  }
```

and also that is the code where i make a post to fireStore

```
final CollectionReference _userCollectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Cars');
  ProductModel? productModel;
  Future<DocumentReference<Object?>> addDataToFireStore(
    String image,
    String name,
    String description,
    String price,
    String number,
  ) async {
    return await _userCollectionRef.add({
      'name': name,
      'description': description,
      'image': image,
      'price': price,
      'country': box.read(NAME_OF_CONTRY),
      'number': number,
      'uid': box.read('uid'),
    });
  }
```

and I call the code in UI of the code

with this form

```
CustomButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        controller.addDataToFireStore(
                          '${methodGetimage(controller)}',
                          name.text,
                          description.text,
                          price.text,
                          number.text,
                        );
                      },
                      text: 'add post',
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                    ),
```

I have created an method that to return the URL of image when it uploaded to storage

```
 methodGetimage(ImageViewModel controller) async {
    var randome = Random().nextInt(1000000);

    File file = File(controller.selectedImagePath.value);
    var imagename = basename(controller.selectedImagePath.value);

    imagename = '$imagename$randome';
    var refstoreg = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('cars/$imagename');
    await refstoreg.putFile(file);

    var url = await refstoreg.getDownloadURL();

    return url;
  }
```

when i make upload there is a text in image filed in firestore which it is `Instance of 'Future<String>'`

Answer (score 0):

`methodGetimage` is an `async` function, and you do not use `await` to get it's result.

Instead of this code:

```
onPressed: () {
  controller.addDataToFireStore(
    '${methodGetimage(controller)}',
    name.text,
    description.text,
    price.text,
    number.text,
  );
},
```

try this:

```
onPressed: () {
  controller.addDataToFireStore(
    await methodGetimage(controller), // note the await keyword here
    name.text,
    description.text,
    price.text,
    number.text,
  );
},
```